# Using existing 14/3 to power two lights and a fan

Tags: electrical, wiring, light

The Panasonic Vent fan/Light I bought has awful color temperature that doesn't match the rest of the lighting in the room. I'd like to use the fan as a fan only and install small cans to provide lighting.

There is an existing 14/3 from two switches to the fan/light for individual control. I would like to take this 14/3 to a junction box in the attic and bring two 14/2s out. One 14/2 would connect the black to the black of the 14/3, the neutrals would be wired together. The other 14/2 would connect the black to the 14/3 red and again share the neutral. This wire would go to the can lights.

Any code violations with this method or do I have to run a new 14/2 up from the switch to the attic?

Answer (score 4):

Rather that adding a new junction box, use the new fan/light fixture as the junction box. Run a new 14/2 cable into it. You can probably fit it in the same connection as the 14/3. Then black from the 14/3 to black from fixture fan. Red from 14/3 to black from new 14/2. Neutral from fan unit to white from 14/3 and white from 14/2. The other end of the 14/2 goes to your new lights.

You can add your additional junction box if you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

That should be fine. It is similar to "split an MWBC in two directions instead of using top/bottom of duplex receptacle". The key is that all hots in each cable are always equally matched to the neutral in that cable.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices here.

1. Since the loads are very small, you could simply connect both outcoming 14/2s black to black, neutral to neutral, ground to ground and cap off the red wire. Also, check the panel to see where that red wire is going.  If you choose this approach,  you'll need to disconnect it and cap it off.
2. If you decide to wire one of the runs using the red, you are effectively creating a MWBC (Multi Wire Branch Circuit). In fact, you may already have a MWBC.  Doing so requires that the red and black in the panel are on opposite legs AND here is the big **AND**  they must be on handle tied breakers to be code legal. Double stuff breakers won't be acceptable bc they are on the same hot.

Edit:  some others have said this is NOT a MWBC, the OP will need to verify the feed.  Re-reading the post, I agree.  The 14/3 was probably intended to separately control the light and fan.

Comment: This is NOT an MWBC. It's two different switched hots with 0 volts between them, as they come from the same unswitched hot, unless something is truly bizzare here, and I see no mention of that in the question.

Comment: Good point guys. So in my answer only point 1 will work.   Thanks for the input.

Comment: Except that the OP has a switch for the lights and a switch for the fan. Wiring both the lights and fan to the black in the /3 will put them all on one switch.

Comment: @FreeMan   That's not what I meant .   Hard to be precise given limited info.  I would assume the OP would simply connect the 2 14/2 cables to individual switches powering both via  a pig tail.   oh well, I must be missing something.  I've been spraying lacquer for most of the afternoon, maybe I'm high!  LOL Just kidding,  and yes, I do spray outside and wear a high end respirator.

Comment: That's how I read "connect both outcoming 14/2s black to black...cap off the red wire". Without using the red wire from the /3 going to the existing fan/light, everything will be on the same switch. Maybe get a breath of fresh air and a good night's sleep and you'll be able to reword it in the morning. :D